What happens if the first segment after a 3-way handshake in a TCP connection is dropped
If I have a scenario with two hosts. Host A and Host B. Let's say that Host A initiates a TCP connection to host B. Let's say a connection has been established after a 3-way handshake. What happens if the very first segment which Host A sends to Host B (after the handshake) is lost/dropped. We can see in the first image that the second segment is lost so duplicate acks of first segment are constantly sent to host A because acks are cumulative. I don't understand what would happen if the first data segment, sent after the handshake, is dropped. What ack # would get sent within the timeout interval in this case.
My assumption here is that this involves the initial 3-way handshake. We have an ack # = x + 1 shown in the second diagram when the 3-way handshake is completed. Therefore I assume an ack # of x + 1 keeps getting sent until retransmission occurs in the fast retransmit diagram(first image). Is my understanding correct?



Answer: Host will timeout waiting for expected ACK from Receiver. When this happens, it will retransmit.  It's not different from the second packet scenario you show above.  What do you find confusing between "second packet" dropped vs "first packet dropped" ?

I was confused because multiple segments (most likely) get sent within the time interval. If the first segment is dropped what ack # does the subsequent segments that do reach Host B send back to Host A. I assumed it was ACKnum = x + 1 because it technically was the last ack that Host A recieved but this occurs during the 3-way handshake so I don't know if this is actually true.

Let's say A sends 3 packets to start the TCP flow after the 3-way handshake.

{seq=92, size=8}
{seq=100, size=20}
{seq=120, size=10}

Let's say that first packet gets lost on the network, but B receives the second and third.  B will actually drop the second and third packets because it will observe that the sequence numbers (100 and 120) are ahead of what's expected (92). Remember, B's state machine machine after the 3-way handshake knows what the first sequence number is supposed to be.
So it treats both of the packets that have arrived out of sequence as not arriving at all.
A patiently waits for the first ACK which never arrives. Eventually it times out and will retransmit the data starting at sequence=92.
I'm saying it retransmits the data and not necessarily the same packet sizes. It could choose to send a single TCP segment with seq=92 and size=38.

I have a better illustration that shows what occurs in the first image. This is from the Computer Networking textbook by James Kuross and Keith Ross.
[https://imgur.com/a/x42FfNl]
Wouldn't the second and third packet you show just get queued/buffered. They don't get dropped but rather would be waiting for the lost segment to get retransmitted. I suppose an implementation could be made where they could get dropped but as far as I am aware in TCP it is ideal to not drop segments.

Note that this assumes the connection does not have selective acknowledgment enabled.

https://imgur.com/a/x42FfNl
here is the image, couldn't edit my original comment
